# Link in email being hidden (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, email

I am sending emails out from my Laravel 5.1 website, via Sendgrid. All is working well, except for one email I have which has a link. This link appears just fine for emails opened by Gmail, but is 'hidden' in Hotmail. Specifically, I see this string in hotmail:
[mysite.com/mylink]Post review

The code is as follows. I suspect it's a CSS/HTML issue. Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you:

```
<a style="color: #fff;
        background-color: #5bc0de;
        border-color: #46b8da;display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
        touch-action: manipulation;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        background-image: none;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-decoration:none" href="{{env('APP_DOMAIN')}}/mylink"><b>Post review</b></a>
```

Comment: How you can say that it's a css issue?

Comment: you are facing problem with CSS stuffs or sending mail ?

Comment: The email is being sent fine, but just not displaying as intended in Hotmail. True, I'm not sure it's necessarily a CSS issue, I'm quite new to this after all. Thanks